# CSS div:hover per menu item having Child and Sibling Selectors issue

Tags: css, css-selectors, parent-child

Site:  http://avuedesigns.com/index

On the front page there is 6 menu items. I would like to have each item have there own color when you over over it.

this is the line that changes everything to white when you hover over the div

```
li#home-page.page-wrapper-li>div>div:hover .div-bg-color { background-color:#ffffff ;}
```

For each menu item I already went in and gave them ID's. When I try this:

```
 li#home-page.page-wrapper-li#front-page-menu-id-about>div:hover.div-bg-color {background-color:#765478 ;}
```

I thought it would work since I am declaring >DIV>div:hover instead of using the operator. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your second line of code appears to have 2 ids on one `li` element, which is not allowed.

Comment: Looked at that link for 5 seconds and started to get a headache. STOP THAT SHAKING!

Comment: Using the what operator?

Comment: The second selector is wrong `li#home-page.page-wrapper-li #front-page-menu-id-about:hover>.div-bg-color {background-color:#765478 ;}` But I do find it wrong to use such huge selectors...

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think you are over-complicating your selectors.

```
#front-page-menu-id-graphic-design a {background: red ;}
```

I don't see any unique ids or classes for each of your `a` tags. Also, I noticed you are using the same Ids on multiple elements, which is not a good idea.